# Add default values to new table row when using the Tab key?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, excel-tables, listobject

I'm currently working on a project in which the user needs to add new rows into a table and each column value has to have a definded default state.

This was quite simple using an ActiveX button that has the following code inside:

```
Private Sub cmdAddRowPiezas01_Click()
    Dim ThisSheetRef As Worksheet
    Set ThisSheetRef = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Piezas")
    
    Dim myRow As ListRow
    Dim intRows As Integer
    
    Dim strNoData As String
    strNoData = "N/A"
    
    intRows = ThisSheetRef.ListObjects("tblPiezas01").ListRows.Count
    intRows = intRows + 1
    Set myRow = ThisSheetRef.ListObjects("tblPiezas01").ListRows.Add(intRows)

    myRow.Range(1) = intRows
    myRow.Range(2) = strNoData
    myRow.Range(3) = strNoData
    
End Sub
```

As you can see, what I'm doing is just adding a new row at the end of the "tblPiezas01" table and setting the values of each cell... but the user needs to click the button for this to happen.

**Is there a way for me to make this code execute when they hit the "TAB" key at the end of the table instead?**

It'd make the process of adding pre-formatted rows way easier (this table only has 3 columns, but I've got several others that include up to 10 columns some with different pre-established values.)

I've scoured the internet for a bit but I've run into the fact that Excel hasn't a built in "AddRow" event, I've seen some solutions that use the "Worsheet_Change" but so far I've got no luck making it work :/ (The code executes EVERY time the worksheet changes, therefore when I set the cell's value to something it triggers again... and that in turn triggers it again and so on).

Comment: If they hit tab, a new row is already added automatically. If you just want to have default values for a table, you can use calculated column formulas, such as `=A2+1`, or `="N/A"` and no need for VBA at all.

Comment: If you're adding the value of the last cell (i.e. the bottom-most right-most cell) manually, which includes pasting anything into the whole last row, using the Worksheet Change event is still an option. Please confirm.

Comment: If you do want to use the Worksheet_Change function and avoid the problem you stated, you could change it to for example `If myRow.Range(2) = "" Then myRow.Range(2) = strNoData`

Comment: @kevin Hi! I tried this approach but ran into the problem that as soon as the user changes the first formula of `="N/A"` to it's desired value, the next row doesn't carry over that formula. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @kevin regarding the use of `If myRow.Range(2) = "" Then myRow.Range(2) = strNoData` wouldn't this _still_ trigger the Worksheet_Change function again?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the user does add the value of the bottom-most right-most cell manually, yes, but I'm not following how that would help me with the fact that the Worksheet_Change event would trigger again as soon as the value for the next row is set. I'm a bit new to VBA so I'm really sorry if there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: For calculated column - you have to highlight the whole column and paste the ="N/A" formula into the whole column as a formula. So if you already have some manual values, you would need to save those somewhere else, then add the column formula, then paste your manual values back to the table. For the `If` - no it will not trigger the function again because after the first time it fires, your row will no longer be blank, so it will not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To add a calculated column if your column already has manual data:

1: copy your existing data to a new range temporarily

2: highlight the entire column of each column that you want to have a default value. Here column a is `=A7+1`, column b & c are `="N/A"`

3: tab to add a new row to your table first. Then paste your original data back into your table. The calculated formulas should work.

[image]

If you don't want the green error flags, you can turn them off in Options > Formulas > Inconsistent calculated column formula in tables

[image]

Comment: This is a nice and easy solution! I might implement a "cleaner" approach so that there's no formula and just the value.



Actually, what I ended up coming up with after reading your comments is that you were right with your `If` idea! I'll modify my code and post back the full solution of my final implementation, thank you so much to you and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

- If the bottom-right cell is non-blank after change, adding a new row is triggered.
- The change of other cells in table (ListObject) doesn't trigger it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Const TAB_NAME As String = "tblPiezas01"
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Len(Target.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
        Set LO = Me.ListObjects(TAB_NAME)
        If Not Application.Intersect(LO.Range.Columns(LO.ListColumns.Count), Target) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Offset(1).ListObject Is Nothing Then
                Dim myRow As ListRow
                Dim strNoData As String
                strNoData = "N/A"
                Set myRow = LO.ListRows.Add
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                myRow.Range(1) = LO.ListRows.Count
                myRow.Range(2) = strNoData
                myRow.Range(3) = strNoData
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

- Remove the last row if users double click any cell on the last row

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Const TAB_NAME As String = "tblPiezas01"
    If Target.ListObject.Name = TAB_NAME Then
        Set LO = Target.ListObject
        If Target.Offset(1).ListObject Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            LO.ListRows(LO.ListRows.Count).Delete
            Cancel = True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an excellent implementation! The only comment I would have is that when the user "finishes" the table it would still add another new unecessary row, however I think that tweaking the code a bit might do the trick!

If I could I would upvote this! But I don't have enough reputation for it yet (I literally signed up to stack overflow just to ask this question)

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Add New Row to Excel Table (`ListObject`)

- Out-comment or remove the `Debug.Print` lines after investigating.
- The thing I don't like is that it adds a new line after pressing `TAB` even when there is already a new line. Shouldn't be an issue. If it is, it would require some code to delete it.
- What I added is that if the last cell is empty it will not add a new row if `TAB` is not pressed.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const NO_DATA_STRING As String = "N/A"
    Const TABLE_NAME As String = "tblPiezas01"
    
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = Target.Worksheet.ListObjects(TABLE_NAME)
    
    Dim tcell As Range:
    With lo.DataBodyRange
        Set tcell = .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(tcell, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rrg As Range, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With lo.DataBodyRange
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Set rrg = .Rows(rCount)
    End With
Debug.Print rrg.Address, rCount, cCount
    
    Dim WasNewRowAdded As Boolean, IsRightCellEmpty As Boolean
    
    If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = cCount Then
        WasNewRowAdded = True
    Else
        If IsEmpty(rrg.Cells(cCount)) Then
            IsRightCellEmpty = True
        End If
    End If
    
Debug.Print IsRightCellEmpty, WasNewRowAdded
    
    If Not IsRightCellEmpty Then
        If Not WasNewRowAdded Then
            lo.ListRows.Add
            Set rrg = lo.ListRows(lo.ListRows.Count).Range
            rCount = rCount + 1
        End If
Debug.Print rrg.Address, rCount, cCount
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            rrg.Cells(1) = rCount
            rrg.Resize(, cCount - 1).Offset(, 1).Value = NO_DATA_STRING
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This idea is also awesome! I might implement it and run some tests with the users, it shouldn't be too big of an issue the little unintented behaviour of a new line even if there's a new line.